# Implementing a reinforced invoice?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, contract-invocation

I have a question. My contract structure involves 2 user at address A and B respectively:

First A trigger the logging method from the contract with B's address as parameter. This will record a mapping from B to A's address in the contract state.

Then B trigger the demand method from the contract. This will send a demand to A's address with an amount that B wanted A to pay.
Then A approve or decline the transaction.

I'm having trouble thinking about how to implement this in Solidity.

1. What data structure should I use to store the mapping from B to A?
2. Can another pair, C and D, reuse the same contract? If yes, how and will the cost of running the contract increase due to the state mapping?

Also, is there a way to enforce it in the contract such that A must approve and cannot decline the payment?